# O que significa essas perguntas que estão aparecendo "semi transparente"?

Tags: suporte

Várias perguntas estão aparecendo como "semi transparentes" na lista de perguntas do **SOpt**.
O que significa essas perguntas que estão aparecendo "semi transparente"?

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você deve ter marcado a tag [html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) como "ignorada", seja propositalmente ou acidentalmente. Como ambas as perguntas mostradas têm essa tag, e ambas estão apagadas, deve ser essa a tag.

Ao passar o mouse sobre uma tag, aparece uma estrela cinza no topo. Isso significa que ela é uma tag "normal" (i.e. não ignorada, nem favorita). Ao clicar nela, alterna-se entre esses três estados (estrela amarela: favorita; "x" vermelho: ignorada). Isso afeta o modo como as perguntas com essa tag são exibidas na lista.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]