# Proposta: "Casual Friday"

Tags: debate, perguntas, escopo-do-site

Gostaria de revisitar um assunto já polêmico no site: **Code Golf**. Atualmente esse tópico [está com votação positiva no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1027/215) (+22/-11), e [nas discussões](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1366/215) a maioria das opiniões são a de que, no mínimo, não faria mal ao site. Mas a resistência continua. Vários usuários não querem esse conteúdo no site, alguns com bons motivos e outros nem tanto, mas de qualquer forma não seria legal passar por cima da opinião deles.

Proponho um meio-termo então: durante os fins de semana (sábados e domingos) a atividade no site cai bastante ([evidência](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1703/up-vs-down-votes-by-week-day#resultSets)). Que tal aceitarmos essas perguntas somente nesses dois dias?

Dessa forma elas não vão se misturar com as perguntas sérias durante os dias da semana - em que a maioria do pessoal está concentrada no trabalho, e não quer saber de distrações. Mas ainda serão permitidas nos períodos de menor atividade, que por sinal é o melhor momento para quem está querendo ampliar seus horizontes (aprender coisas novas, praticar, etc, num momento que as obrigações do trabalho não sejam prioridade).

O que acham? Sugiro tratar essa pergunta como "pesquisa de opinião" (*poll question*), onde as diferentes opções podem ser expostas e votadas ("sim, concordo com tudo", "sim, mas com ressalvas", "não, tem que poder code golf sempre", "não, não pode ter code golf nunca", etc). Mas se alguém tiver algo a acrescentar, motivos pra achar que essa é uma ideia ruim por exemplo, fique à vontade pra responder de acordo. (**Atualização:** já que ninguém postou respostas, preferindo expor sua opinião em forma de comentário, coloquei as opções consideradas para apreciação)

P.S. Na minha opinião *pessoal*:

- Uma meta-tag "code-golf" é interessante sim, assim quem quiser pode [ignorá-la](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1219/215);
- As respostas a um code golf deveriam ser *community wiki*, assim as pessoas podem votar a favor e contra sem influência nos pontos de reputação;
- Pode-se restringir as **respostas** a um code golf aos fins de semana também, de modo que elas não poluam a aba "ativo".

E finalmente: eu não acho que uma regra dessas "abre precedente pra todo tipo de conteúdo indesejável no site" - qualquer proposta de tópico seja em caráter restrito ou irrestrito precisaria passar pelo mesmo escrutínio que o tópico de code golf passou.

Comment: Particularmente, eu gostei da ideia de restringir o período aceito para esse tipo de perguntas apenas para Sábado/Domingo. Acho que essa restrição seria capaz de mudar os votos do, já citado tópico sobre code-golf.  Mas, até que ponto isso iria atrapalhar as questões sérias de Sábado/Domingo?.. Essa é a única questão que não consegui encontrar uma saída.

Comment: O StackExchange já tem um site para CodeGolf, veja [aqui](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles) e [aqui](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). Eu vejo o StackOverflow como um site para perguntas sérias, para perguntas de CodeGolf use o site [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Cara , o perigo é que isso tudo vai ficar indexado pelo Google, novos usuários vão entrar sem ter contexto, visualizar as perguntas, tentarem algo parecido e terem questões fechadas e negativadas. Temos que partir para um lado ou para o outro, ou aceitamos Code Golf ou não.

Comment: @emanuelsn Elas iriam atrapalhar na mesma medida que aquelas malditas perguntas sobre `asp.net-mvc` (que não me interessam em nada) tornam mais difícil eu encontrar os assuntos realmente úteis, como `django` (j/k). O fato é que apenas um percentual pequeno das perguntas no SO interessa a qualquer usuário em particular, encontrá-las no meio do fluxo de novas perguntas (ainda lento aqui, muito mais frenético no SOen) já requer um esforço ativo. A inclusão de um novo tópico de fato aumenta o volume, mas não demais (já temos tantos tópicos), e é contrabalanceado pela baixa atividade nesses dias.

Comment: @Andrey O StackExchange também já tem um site para perguntas de programação, chama-se stackoverflow.com :P Brincadeiras à parte, respeito sua opinião, e se ela for maioria eu não tenho problemas em acatá-la. Mas cada um tem uma visão diferente do que é o SO, e *me parece* que há um número expressivo de pessoas que discorda de sua visão. Coloquei essa proposta no sentido de tentar conciliar as visões conflitantes, e não simplesmente aplicar a "ditadura da maioria" (code golf está com votação positiva? então pode e pronto! ih, agora a votação ficou negativa? não pode e fim de papo! etc).

Comment: Acho isso de "aceitar" um pouco estranho... Ou aceita ou não aceita. *Recomendar* a postagem no fim de semana me parece boa idéia.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Sim, essa é uma preocupação válida. Só me pergunto o quanto o problema é gerenciável ou não. Todos os dias novos usuários postam perguntas inadequadas (fora do foco do site, subjetivas, baseadas em opinião, "façam meu trabalho pra mim", etc), mas a comunidade lida com elas numa boa. Nesse caso complica um pouco mais, pela presença de uma regra *ad-hoc* (só pode nos fins de semana), mas a diferença é pequena IMHO. Isso até poderia ser mitigado se a regra fosse institucionalizada (ex.: o sistema mostra um alerta se a tag for usada em dias errados), mas acho difícil acatarem isso.

Comment: @mgibsonbr É justo que isso seja discutido, ninguém é obrigado a concordar comigo, só estou mostrando a minha opinião, estou aberto a ouvir as outras =) Eu sou a favor de tornar o escopo do Stack-PT mais flexível para as perguntas que trazem algo de útil ao site, possam ajudam alguém, etc... Só não acho até agora que esse seja o caso do CodeGolf, mas talvez ainda mude de opinião um dia =)

Comment: Acho que aceita ou não. Os três bullets que você colocou são ótimos motivos para não ter Code Golf. Se tem que fazer exceção ao modelo, tem problema neste tipo de pergunta. Já disse várias vezes que não gosto delas mas não vejo problema em qualquer dia da semana. Não quer participar, é só se abster. Tem tempo no final de semana? Ótimo, aproveite nestes dias. Pra mim causa mais problemas (não causa de verdade, não tenho nada contra, é só um exemplo do que não me interessa porque ignoro totalmente) ter perguntas sobre R do que Code Golf :) Depois eu vi que você já escreveu tudo isto nos comments

Comment: @bigown Esses bullets são minha resposta pessoal a duas críticas que percebo no code golf: 1 e 3) vai me distrair dos assuntos sérios; e 2) as pessoas vão ganhar pontos de reputação com bobagem. Se esses dois argumentos forem refutados, não há necessidade dos bullets. De todo modo, achei uma ótima diretriz: "Se tem que fazer exceção ao modelo, tem problema neste tipo de pergunta".

Comment: O principal problema que vejo é como lidar com quem desobedecer uma regra assim por ignorância. Como o @AnthonyAccioly falou, um usuário pode ver uma questão e querer postar uma similar. Deve ser negativada e fechada **só** por está no dia errado? E se for uma resposta? Deve ser negativada/excluída? Edições nas postagens também ficam proibidos durante a semana? Com o número de perguntas crescendo, não tem moderação que segure. Meu ponto: Limitar a um dia só trás mais problema do que permitir todo o dia ou proibir de vez. É melhor que seja tomada uma decisão de verdade quanto a isso. Mas qual?

Answer (score 13):

## Não, o foco deve ser o mesmo o tempo todo

Regras diferentes para dias diferentes é difícil de se gerenciar. Se um assunto está no foco, deve ser permitido sempre, e se não está, não deve ser permitido nunca. De modo que a aceitação do tópico Code Golf deve ser [decidido por maioria simples](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1027/215) como todos os outros.

Caso aceito, pode-se por simples etiqueta recomendar o fim de semana para essas perguntas, porém sem ônus para aqueles usuários que não seguirem essa recomendação.

Comment: Meu único adendo é que talvez para [tag:code-golf] talvez o ideal seria recomendar o uso exclusivo dessa tag para não poluir as outras.

Comment: Lembrei na hora [desta resposta do Jan](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3608/12615) pra uma pergunta do Jan :P

Answer (score 4):

## Não, pois os posts na rede Stack Exchange são atemporais

Seria contraprodutivo aceitar ou refutar conteúdo baseado no dia da semana, pois de duas uma:

- Teremos que nos dar ao trabalho de verificar a data das perguntas antes de decidir se devem ser aceitas ou suspensas;
- Labirinto semântico: qual é o limite do final de semana? E o que ocorre com um post de golfe de código que continue popular após isso? Devemos fechar as perguntas de golfe de código à meia noite do domingo para a segunda-feira? Reabrimos a pergunta na sexta-feira/sábado?

Posts são atemporais. É ridículo, por exemplo, quando um post começa com "bom dia" ou "boa noite", pois os demais usuários leem esses posts em diferentes horários. Aceitar conteúdo com base em data-hora é levar essa estranha cultura um nível além.

Comment: Esta proposta não é igual a ***"Não, o foco deve ser mesmo o tempo todo"***?

Comment: Não tem *ranting* o suficiente na outra resposta.

Comment: "Teremos que nos dar ao trabalho de verificar a data das perguntas antes de decidir se devem ser aceitas ou suspensas;" oi? não sei quanto a você, mas eu não preciso fazer nenhum esforço ativo pra saber se hoje é ou não um dia de semana... Não vou me alongar demais, pois a comunidade já decidiu (e eu estou super satisfeito com o resultado BTW), mas às vezes me espanta a resistência que as pessoas têm à possibilidade de mudança. Pra quem não sabe, várias funcionalidades que hoje temos por garantidas (ex.: marcar como duplicata) não foram projetadas desde o início, mas **emergiram** a partir do

Comment: comportamento da comunidade (o hábito que as pessoas tinham de editar a pergunta e linkar **manualmente** pra possível duplicata no topo, usando a formatação disponível pra dar destaque). Foi só ao ver como a comunidade estava agindo - e perceber que isso era bom - que a funcionalidade foi **institucionalizada** de fato (i.e. implementada no site). Mas aqui o pessoal cita dificuldades técnicas como obstáculo pras mudanças mais simples! É a velha falácia: se uma ação não consegue ter 100% de sucesso ela não deve ser feita em absoluto... (pronto! agora essa resposta tem *ranting* suficiente :P)

Comment: @mgibsonbr O Renan se referiu (claramente, diga-se de passagem) ao cuidado extra de olhar a data da PERGUNTA (não o dia atual). Pelo menos para mim não é automático saber se o dia 26/08 foi um sábado ou um domingo, exigindo um cuidado extra na hora de votar pra fechar (não é por que eu estou vendo uma pergunta na terça que ela foi feita na terça).

Comment: @Beterraba Eu entendi, só não achei necessário dizer com todas as letras: "olha, eu até entendo que pode ser necessário avaliar em retrospecto uma pergunta feita dias atrás, se ninguém mais na comunidade o fez em tempo. Mas o mais comum é uma pergunta ser vista pouco tempo depois dela ser feita, de modo que ela pode ser fechada imediatamente sem muito esforço cognitivo. Se uma pergunta por acaso passar despercebida, paciência, *tumbleweed* nela... Eu não acho isso tão importante, pois <<rant>>". Simplesmente soltei a piada e pronto! Se soou ofensivo, peço desculpas, não foi minha intenção...

Answer (score 0):

## Não, pois o tópico é problemático

A necessidade de uma regra especial evidencia os problemas do tópico Code Golf, de modo que este não deve ser considerado como conteúdo próprio ao site. Sendo assim, sua aceitação não deve ser [decidida por maioria simples](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1027/215), mas sim por consenso, permanecendo *off-topic* a menos que todos os principais problemas com esse tópico sejam sanados.

Answer (score -3):

## Sim, mas sem restrições quanto ao formato

Podemos adotar uma regra *ad hoc* de somente aceitar esse tópico nos fins de semana, porém sem restrições ao formato: não haverá meta-tag `code-golf`, e as respostas não serão obrigatoriamente wiki da comunidade, gerando pontos de reputação normalmente.

A ação sugerida é fechar esse tipo de pergunta caso seja feita em dia de semana, possivelmente reabrindo-a no fim de semana subsequente (e mantendo-a aberta a partir de então). Alternativamente, removendo-a do site em absoluto, seguida ou não de *undelete* no dia apropriado.

Answer (score -4):

## Sim, nos moldes propostos

Podemos adotar uma regra *ad hoc* de somente aceitar esse tópico nos fins de semana, desde que as perguntas se atenham aos moldes propostos:

- Identificação através da meta-tag [gode-golf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gode-golf) (com esclarecimento no wiki da tag sobre sua aplicabilidade restrita aos fins de semana);
- Respostas no formato wiki da comunidade.

A ação sugerida é fechar esse tipo de pergunta caso seja feita em dia de semana, possivelmente reabrindo-a no fim de semana subsequente (e mantendo-a aberta a partir de então). Alternativamente, removendo-a do site em absoluto, seguida ou não de *undelete* no dia apropriado.